# Importing a csv file to a Postgres table from different computers ( hence, different paths)

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, path, jupyter-notebook

First of all thanks, I'm no expert in programming.
I work with jupyter notebooks and with my boss we use a Dropbox folder where he is able to run all my codes( including exporting and importing files within the folder), since it is possible to run jupyter notebook from within a desired folder( in this case, the Dropbox one). Based on this, when importing files I can just type a path like this one: "Dropxboxsharedfolder/some-otherfolder/jdjd.csv" and it will find the file in both of our computers.

Now we are running SQL scripts through Jupyter, of course, the .SQL file is within the Dropbox folder, but the script has within itself a code where I import a CSV file located inside the Dropbox folder. Nevertheless (of course, it won't) it won't let me just type the path as "dropboxsharedfolder/somefolder/djdhjd.csv" I have to type "User/username/dropboxsharedfolder/.../jdjd.csv". At the end, when my boss runs the notebook it won't work cause it won't find the file.

Is there a solution for this situation?

Thank you so much for your time!

Pd: we use postgresSQL

Answer (score 0):

You could use an environment variable to point to the shared dropbox folder on each computer (the value of the variable would be set accordingly on each computer) and use the environment variable in your script instead of hardcoded paths